# How do I use a controller to call a REST webservice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

My code is below, and I'm pretty new to angular.  I have a controller that I want to call a webservice (already written by someone else).  That call will happen after a user enters a sku and vendor number and clicks 'search.'

```
<div ng-controller="inventorySearchController">

    <div class="container">


        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class=""><input ng-model="skuField" type="text"  my-maxlength="10" placeholder="Sku Number" data-ng-model=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=""><input ng-model="mVendorField" type="text"  my-maxlength="10" placeholder="M-Vendor Number"  data-ng-model=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class=""><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="inventorySearchController.callService()" value="Search" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </div>
</div>

(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('specificLoadApp').controller('inventorySearchController', inventorySearchController);

    inventorySearchController.$inject = ['$scope','$http'];


    function inventorySearchController($scope, $http) {

        var callService = function(){

        var urlSearchService = 'http://myorginaztion.com/services/search';
        var skuVal = $scope.skuField;
        var mVenVal = $scope.mVendorField;
        var xml = "<ItemSearchRequest>"
                        +"<skuid>" + skuVal + "</skuid>"
                        +"<mvendor>" + mVenVal + "</mvendor>"
                    +"</ItemSearchRequest>";

        console.log('calling: ' + urlSearchService);
        $http.post(urlSearchService, xml).
            success(function(data){
                $scope.searchResults = data;
                console.log('call to ' + urlSearchService + ", was a success.");
            });
    };

};
})();
```

Comment: for whatever reason, I couldn't also include the html.

Comment: can you please tell us what error our web service call throws..?

Comment: that's the thing... none of my console.log or console.error statements are doing anything.  It's like when I click the search button nothing happens at all.

Comment: no just see the network panel..you might see the reason for our service failure

Comment: I'm just getting one 200 response.  But nothing else, and nothing to the console either.

Comment: if you are getting 200 then that's mean our service call executed successfully,what is the problem then..?

Comment: Is that 200 from a call to `callService()`?

Answer (score 4):

It appears like `callService` is not bound to `$scope`. Try changing

```
var callService = function(){
```

to

```
$scope.callService = function(){
```

Comment: this is correct. you want to add things to the `$scope` so they can be accessed in other functions or in binding expressions

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just getting started, avoid using $scope and instead use controller as syntax.

So in your div, where you load the controller, change it to:

```
<div ng-controller="inventorySearchController as inventorySearch">
```

And where you create the button change it to read:

```
<td class=""><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="inventorySearch.callService()" value="Search" /></td>
```

Then lastly, in your controller, change you controller so that the first line reads: `var vm=this;`

and finally, change the function definition for call service to read:

```
vm.callService = function(){...}
```

The controller as syntax is generally considered a best practice and follows the guideline of "if you're not using a dot, you're doing it wrong."

You will also no longer need to inject $scope if you go this route.

Your bindings should be prefixed with inventorySearch as well if you make this change.